# When I write in a TextBox with Calcul behind then comes directly the Result in another TextBox

Tags: excel, vba

I have one UserForm with 1 TextBox and 1 ComboBox.

I firstly write in the ComboBox (per exemple Sarah)

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CalculSheet").Range("A2").Value = ComboBox1.Text
End Sub
```

Then it makes some calcul in A3 like (If D2=Sarah Then D3=1)

```
Private Sub UserForm_Active()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CalculSheet").Activate
TextBox1 = Range("A3").Value

End Sub
```

And I want that the Result comes directly in my TextBox1. It means that I write Sarah in the ComboBox1 and directly comes 1 in the TextBox1.

Comment: there isn't any event called `Active`. You could find and possibly use `Activate` event

Comment: Sorry, it's activate, but doesn't work too((

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `Private Sub UserForm_Active()` code. You don't need that. Replace `ComboBox1_Change()` with this.

Is this what you are trying? (**Untested**)

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CalculSheet")
        .Range("A2").Value = ComboBox1.Text
        DoEvents
        TextBox1.Text = .Range("A3").Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Comment: I'm Trying to make a direct calcul but it doesnt work correctly: Private Sub TextBox270_AfterUpdate()
TextBox223.Value = Val(TextBox1.Value) + Val(TextBox150.Value)
End Sub It means 1+2 = 3 in TextBox223 per exemple

Comment: This is not part of your original question. Please ask a different question for a different query. As far as this question is concerned it has been answered as per your comment `Many Thanks!! It's working welll)) –  Chris 2 hours ago`

Comment: Also please do not delete your comments. My comments look as if I am talking to myself. I have deleted my comment as well now.

Comment: Ok Sorry I will make a new question